# android Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.

Tags: android, gradle

hi i have a android project which when i want get release.apk it shows up this error I got version yesterday and it was fine

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Error while executing java process with main class com.android.dx.command.Main with arguments {--dex --num-threads=4 --multi-dex --main-dex-list D:\android\projects\android-client\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\release\maindexlist.txt --output D:\android\projects\android-client\app\build\intermediates\transforms\dex\release\0 --min-sdk-version 17 D:\android\projects\android-client\app\build\intermediates\transforms\jarMerging\release\0.jar}

whats is this all about?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and then rebuilding your project?

Comment: @JanStoltman yes i havve